# DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP vs UNIX sleep

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql, sleep

I have a shell script which will trigger a PL/SQL report generation procedure after certain pre-conditions are satisfied. The logic for checking whether the pre-conditions are fulfilled is written in PL/SQL package. The report generation needs to wait until the pre-conditions are not fulfilled.

What are the pros and cons of waiting using `dbms_lock.sleep` inside PL/SQL procedure vs UNIX `sleep`?

Comment: As you ask about dbms_lock.sleep, I guess you are in a loop, sleeping some seconds before you check your preconditions again. Why not steering it with locks? Something like: when the preconditions are met, you release a lock (in a trigger maybe) your report procedure is waiting on. No need for a loop and polling ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like a lot of design decisions the answer is, it depends.

Database connections are expensive and relatively time consuming operations. So probably the more efficient approach would be to connect to the database once and let the PL/SQL job handle the waiting process.

Also it's probably cleaner to have a simple PL/SQL call and let the database handle the *report or sleep* logic rather than write an API that returns a state which the calling program must interpret and act on. This also gives you a neater path to alternative execution (say by calling from a GUI or a DBMS_SCHEDULER job).

There are two specific advantages of using a shell script `sleep`:

1. You have the option of emitting a status every time the loop enters sleep mode (if this is interactive)
2. Execute on `sys.dbms_lock` is not granted to anybody by default. Some DBAs can be reluctant to grant execute on that package.

Comment: I guess it should be possible to provide a wrapper for sys.dbms_lock.sleep that limits access to just that procedure.

Comment: @davidaldridge - of course it is possible and indeed recommend but how many DBAs bother to do it? The good news is that Oracle are finally addressing this, and `sleep()` will be added to a public by default package (such as `dbms_session` ) in a future release. The world waits with bated breath...